# Map в groovy, как достать значение по ключу?

Tags: синтаксис, groovy

У меня есть мапа соответствии логинов и почт

```
    def loginEmail = [
"abc": "abc@mail.ru",
"cde": "cde@mail.ru"
]
```

Как мне достать по ключу значение через ключ в методе?

```
def getEmail(String login){
  return loginEmail.get(login)
}
```

Что то типо такого

Comment: println(loginEmail["abc"])

Answer (score 0):

Ваше предположение совершенно верно:

`loginEmail.get('abc')`

Более подробно о работе с `Map`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html